# Rspec factory_girl ActiveMerchant undefined method `credit_card='

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, activemerchant

I'm attempting to test the creation of an Reservation model that involves processing a payment with ActiveMerchant upon creation.

The initial setup for payment processing involved following the ActiveMerchant Railscasts. Payments are working fine within the app. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant)

I've tried creating the `credit_card` object within the `Reservation` factory and within it's own ":valid_credit_card" factory...

The basic test is just attempting to verify the Reservation can be created.
Test results:

```
1) Reservation should have a valid factory
 Failure/Error: @current_reservation = Factory.create(:reservation)
 NoMethodError:
 undefined method `credit_card=' for #<Reservation:0xb5f6173c>
 # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:11
```

The Reservation belongs_to a user and has_many rooms through reservation_sets

```
Factory.define :reservation do |f|
  f.association :user
  f.rooms { |a| [a.association(:room)] }
  f.arrival Time.now + 2.weeks
  f.nights  2
  f.phone "555-123-1234"
  f.credit_card :valid_credit_card
end

Factory.define :valid_credit_card, :class => ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard do |f|
  expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 1.year  
  f.type "visa"
  f.number "4111111111111111"
  f.verification_value "333"
  f.month expiration_date.strftime("%m")
  f.year expiration_date.strftime("%y")
  f.first_name "Bob"
  f.last_name "Smith"
end
```

And the spec/models/reservation_spec.rb. Using @credit_card Factory.build causes errors about "saving" the credit_card.

If I remove the line f.credit_card :valid_credit_card I get the NoMethodError for `:month`
even though `:month` is listed in `attr_accessor`. The creation of a reservation within the app does work.

```
  1) Reservation should have a valid factory
     Failure/Error: @current_reservation = Factory.create(:reservation)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `month' for nil:NilClass

describe Reservation do
  before :each do
    @smith = Factory.create(:user)
    @room = Factory.create(:room)
    #@credit_card = Factory.build(:valid_credit_card) 
  end
  it "should have a valid factory" do
    @current_reservation = Factory.create(:reservation)
    @current_reservation.should be_valid
  end
end
```

What am I overlooking / doing incorrectly...?

Reservation model excerpts

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reservation_sets, 
       :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :rooms, 
           :through => :reservation_sets
  has_many :transactions,
           :class_name => 'ReservationTransaction',
           :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification, :card_expires_on, :card_type, :ip_address, :rtype, :month, :year
  # other standard validations
  validate :validate_card, :on => :create

  # other reservation methods...
  # gets paid upon reservation creation
  def pay_deposit
    # Generate active merchant object

    ReservationTransaction.gateway = 
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new({
        :login => rooms[0].user.gateway_login,
        :password => rooms[0].user.gateway_password
      }) 

    response = ReservationTransaction.gateway.purchase(deposit_price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
    t = transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => deposit_price_in_cents, :response => response)
    if response.success?
      update_attribute(:reserved_at, Time.now)
      # update state
      payment_captured!
    else
      transaction_declined!
      errors.add :base, response.message
    end
    t.card_number = credit_card.display_number
    t.save!
    response.success?
  end

  def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid?
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        errors.add :base, message #_to_base message
      end
    end
  end

  def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :type               => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expires_on.month,
      :year               => card_expires_on.year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )
  end
```

And the create action from the Reservation Controller

```
  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation])
    @reservation.arrival = session[:arrival]
    @reservation.nights = session[:nights]
    @reservation.number_kids = session[:number_kids]
    @reservation.number_adults = session[:number_adults]
    session[:creating_reservation] = 1
    @reservation.user_id = @reservation.rooms[0].user_id
    session[:owner] = @reservation.user_id
    @rooms = Room.all
    @reservation.ip_address = request.remote_ip         

    # get room owner...
    @owner = User.find(@reservation.user_id) 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        if @reservation.pay_deposit
          #set cc...
          @reservation.transactions[0].card_number = @reservation.send(:credit_card).display_number
          ReservationMailer.reservation_created(@reservation).deliver
          ReservationMailer.reservation_notice(@reservation).deliver
          session[:arrival] = nil
          session[:reservation_id] = @reservation.id
          if @owner 
            thanks_path = "#{@owner.permalink}/reservations/#{@reservation.id}" 
          else
            thanks_path = @reservation
          end
          format.html { redirect_to @reservation, :notice => 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :json => @reservation, :status => :created, :location => @reservation }
          # also trigger email sending or wherever that is 
          # receipt email and order notification
          # 
        else
           # set flash or show message problem w/ transaction 

           format.html { render :action => "new" }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @reservation.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: what does your `reservation` model look like?

Comment: Added some parts of the `reservation` Model and Create action. I know some of this needs to be refactored... Maybe that's part of the problem... Thanks for checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to assign `credit_card` a value, but you don't really have a [class accessor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Class/Accessors.htm). So where you are trying to call `f.credit_card :valid_credit_card` isn't going to work.

I would remove the `f.credit_card :valid_credit_card` from your factory and look into using [rspec stubs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames), then you could do something like the following in your rspec test:

```
mock_cc = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :type               => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expires_on.month,
      :year               => card_expires_on.year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )

Reservation.stub(:credit_card).and_return(mock_cc)
```

This would make it so when your model called `credit_card` it would return a mocked object.

Comment: Thanks, this helped get me pointed in the right direction. In addition to adding an `attr :credit_card` line I was trying to set `f.month` and `f.year` when I should have been setting `f.card_expires_on`. Test passes now.